# Issue with recent selenium jar file of firefox driver cant able to click the element on scrolling down

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

when page moving downwards im trying to an find element  their is  an  floating header in
 that  page that is got hoverd with it menu tabs and doesn't make me to click an element.

**firefox version :45.0.1
Selenium Standalone jar verison :2.53.0**

**Exception is :**

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (849.5, 10.899993896484375). 
Other element would receive the click: XXXX
Command duration or timeout: 90 milliseconds

I've even tried with JavaScript scroll command which doesn't works fine for me
can anyone faced these kind of issue in firefox?

attached sample screenshot for reference.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4jMr.gif)

Code Written:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("abotmembermenulink")).click(); //basic details 
        driver.findElement(By.id("basicmenulink")).click(); 
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", ""); //religion information 
        driver.findElement(By.id("religiousmenulink")).click(); //location 
        driver.findElement(By.id("locationmenulink")).click(); //professionalInformation 
        driver.findElement(By.id("educationmenulink")).click(); 
        driver.findElement(By.id("familymenulink")).click();
```

Comment: Which element do you want to click ? And, please add the code snippet that you've tried so far. It will be easier to help you out. :)

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("abotmembermenulink")).click();
    
    //basic details
    driver.findElement(By.id("basicmenulink")).click();
    
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
    
    //religion information
    driver.findElement(By.id("religiousmenulink")).click();
    
    //location
    driver.findElement(By.id("locationmenulink")).click();
    
    //professionalInformation
    driver.findElement(By.id("educationmenulink")).click();
    
    driver.findElement(By.id("familymenulink")).click();

Comment: None of the locators (ids), as mentioned in the code so attached,  are indicating any element in the page [http://www.sourcehov.com](http://www.sourcehov.com). Please tell, what element, in the page, is not getting clicked .